# Relative xpath with javascript click

Tags: javascript, java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
public void click()
{                               
    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'javascript:toggleEnabled']@href + /a//img[@title='Inactive']"));  
    list.click          
}
```

I am not able to click on title = "Inactive" in javascript console. The HTML code is mentioned below.

```html
<a href="javascript:toggleEnabled('Collaboration: Browse -> Buy');">
 <img src="/console/themes/images/new_imgs/status_light_off.png" style="width:24px; height:24px;" alt="Inactive" title="Inactive">
</a>
```

[ConsoleExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMJxg.png)

[Conslole Example are 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGtJk.png)

[Console example 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6C20.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the `HTML` to click on the `element` you can use the following line of code : :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a/img[contains(@src,'/console/themes/images/new_imgs/status_light_off.png')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting some more info, using `title='Inactive'` was not enough to be unique. Adding a check on the `href` should take care of it. Switching to CSS selector since XPath is not required for this locator.

```
By.cssSelector("a[href*='Buy'][title='Inactive']")
```

Comment: It is clicking on another console light exactly next to it mentioned here <a href="javascript:forceRun('Best sellers');">
<img src="/console/themes/images/new_imgs/status_light_off.png" style="width:24px; height:24px;" alt="Inactive" title="Inactive">
</a>

Comment: It should click on the following html / javascript console...                              <a href="javascript:toggleEnabled('Collaboration: Browse -> Buy');">
 <img src="/console/themes/images/new_imgs/status_light_off.png" style="width:24px; height:24px;" alt="Inactive" title="Inactive">
</a>

Comment: Tried this ::::driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'javascript:toggleEnabled']@href + /a//img[@title='Inactive']"));             but cannot enable to recognise the xpath

Comment: Updated my answer based on the additional HTML.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[href*='Buy'][title='Inactive']"}                 --  Thanks but still error continues.

Comment: Please post a link to the page. Given the HTML that you provided, that locator should work.

Comment: Thanks. But , VPN is required to open the link. I am editing some images in my original post. Green images are On(Active) and Grey images are (Inactive). HTML code also in images.